# Detecting circles in images in C#,I need help to work my code as below

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I have started image processing recently, and I want to write a program for detecting shapes such as circles in images, My sample code is as below but it isn't working:( 
I read most of the related questions and answers in this forum and tried to solve my problem but I haven't been succeed. This code is running but hasn't any proper output.
If any body there to help me, I would be so thankful.

```
        DialogResult x;
        x = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (x == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        pic1.ImageLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(pic1.ImageLocation);
        Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

        BlobCounter blobcounter = new BlobCounter();
        blobcounter.ProcessImage(bmp2);
        blobcounter.FilterBlobs = true;
        blobcounter.MinHeight = bmp2.Height;
        blobcounter.MinWidth = bmp2.Width;

        Blob[] blobs = blobcounter.GetObjectsInformation();

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2);
        SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();
        Pen yellowpen = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < blobs.Length; i++ )
        {
            List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobcounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs[i]);

            AForge.Point center;
            float radius;

            if(shapeChecker.IsCircle(edgePoints, out center, out radius))
            {
                g.DrawEllipse(yellowpen,
                             (int)(center.X - radius),
                             (int)(center.Y - radius),
                             (int)(radius * 2),
                             (int)(radius * 2));
            }
        }
        yellowpen.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: debug your code and find the line where the actual output deviates from the expected output. for anybody to retry this, consider including a sample input bitmap, and info on versions of libraries used. and a more specific problem description :)

Comment: I debug it, unfortunately there is not any presented error or bug:(

Comment: so does `blobs.Length` end up zero? or `shapeChecker.IsCircle` does not ever return true?